# Is it possible to integrade an existing CryFS volume into the KDE vaults menu?

Tags: kde, encryption

I have created a [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org/) volume by command line by entering the following commands:

```
cryfs ~/Dropbox/basedir ~/Documents/Data_Dropbox
```

Is it possible to manage this CryFS volume with KDE vaults?

I am running Kubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, however at the time of writing it is not possible to do this by GUI and you will have to modify the config file: `~/.config/plasmavaultrc`

With the example in the original post, where: ~/Dropbox/basedir is the basedir and ~/Documents/Data_Dropbox is the mount directory.

Add a section for your CryFS volume in the config file:

```
[/home/myusername/Dropbox/basedir]
activities=
backend=cryfs
lastStatus=1
mountPoint=/home/myusername/Documents/Data_Dropbox
name=DropBoxVault
offlineOnly=false
```

And under encrypted devices in the same file

```
[EncryptedDevices]
/home/myusername/Dropbox/basedir=true
```

Note that if you have not created a vault with the Vaults menu, there will be no encrypted devices part. Just copy the [Encrypted Devices] title too.
Logout of plasma and back in (probably there is a simpler way than the latter) and voilà!